# SQL Server Add Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I want to add a column to one of my tables in SQL Server.  I don't want it to be at the end of the column listing in the table...I actually want it to be somewhere else (location wise) in the table.  Is there another option besides dropping and rebuilding (populating) the table to accomplish this? I obviously don't want ot lose any of my data, but I would prefer it not have to have the column at the end of the table definition.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
I agree with OMG Ponies, column order isn't important. If you don't have a clustered index, rather drop and recreate the table than run an *ALTER TABLE x ADD col*.

**Long answer:**
If your table has a fair bit of data (50Mb comes to mind) then you will be better off recreating the table rather than *ALTER TABLE x ADD col*  The data page allocation plan for the table is calculated at table creation time so when you add a column, SQL Server will typically put your new column's data in separate pages and put forward pointers from your existing data pages to the new data pages for the column you added.  If you're going to use the new column extensively then your table IO will be quite poor since reading even 1 row will require reading at least 2 pages.  Table scans will also perform poorly since forward pointers will always be followed, causing table scans that are normally sequential to jump back and forth on your disk during a read.

In this case it's better to rename the existing table, recreate your table with the new column, insert into table_name select col1, col2, 'null or default for new col', col3 from temp_renamed_table and finally drop the old table that you renamed.  The data pages will be much better organised and your IO will be faster despite looking the same from a SQL developer's point of view than when *ALTER TABLE* is used.  If you have a clustered index the table will be reorganised when you add the column and page splits are less likely.  You could also run *ALTER TABLE x REBUILD* if you have SQL Server 2008, don't have a clustered index and lots of time when users aren't using your table.  It's hard to comment on your indexing strategy without knowing much more.

This is a much better reason for recreating the table than something cosmetic like column order.

Comment: Sir Wobin, this is the first I've heard that "new columns" will be added in this way. Can you post some online references that discuss this? (It sounds reasonable, I just want to get a lot more depth and detail on the subject, and I'm not sure how to Google the subject.)

Comment: I like Philip would like to see any docs you have on this...would be really helpful.

Comment: The concepts you're after are 'page splits' and 'forwarding pointers'. Here are 2 excellent discussions with techniques for how to find them on your tables, including experiments to determine when they happen.

http://bit.ly/bIrQvp and http://bit.ly/df3Mp0

Here is a specific reference to page splits happening as a result of adding a column to an existing table.

http://bit.ly/dAxPs0

Comment: (Finaly had time to follow up on this) Page splits, yes, forwarding pointers, yes, but that third example doesn't *add* columns to a table, it *alters* existing rows in the table. Even so, when I have more time I can do some tests based on these examples to figure out what's what.

Answer (score 9):

Column order in the table is irrelevant -- it's purely cosmetic.
There is no extension to `ALTER TABLE` that allows you to specify the ordinal position of a new column (either for adding a new column or moving an existing column).

For more on the subject, see:

- [Change Order of Column In Database Tables](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/08/sql-server-change-order-of-column-in-database-tables/)

Comment: Besides you can always create a view that rearranges the column order as desired.

Answer (score 1):

It is an extremely bad practice to rearrange columns in a table. Do not even consider trying to do such a thing. The column order is irrelevant if you have used correct coding practices (such as never and I do mean never) using select *.

If you have used select * and you change the order of the columns, you are even more at risk of breaking code because the query may not be expecting Price as the third column but as the second column and that could seriously mess up a lot of things.

Further the only way to do this is to create another table, move your data and then drop the old table and rename the first one. Of course if you have FKs, they too have to be dropped and recreated. This takes alot of time if you hav ea large data set and could cause problems for users.

There is no cuircumstance where you would ever consider doing this for a table that in on production as it is just too risky. If you are in the early stages of design, you could consider doing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN column_name VARCHAR(50) AFTER col_name;
```

substituting whatever def you want for VARCHAR(50)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

**Edit** This is of course the right answer for a MySQL server... but this is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, @Gendolkari I thought mysqld was an SQL server. Anyway I can't get anything right today so I'm off to the pub.

Comment: SQL Server is Microsoft's SQL database product -- there's more info in the [wiki associated with the `sql-server` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info). MySQL is a competing product (from Oracle these days).